# How to pass data from Window to MainWindow in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

Im newbie to programming and now i have a problem with my new login window.
I created a new window for login to my server database,but in my mainwindow how do i call it? I don't know how to draw it up better.

In my login window:

```
using MyS_Database;
MyServer_Database server;

public void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    server = new MyServer_Database("ClientName","ServerIP","","",UserID.Text,UserPassword.Password.ToString(),"01",MyServer_Database.LoginType.User,out serverresult)
    swith(serverresult)
    {
    case 0:
    Mainwindow.Show();
    this.Close();
    break;

    default:
    Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

But when I call a method on my MainWindow which is communicating with the server i have to call it like:

```
server.GetDataFromUserList();
```

But It doesn't recognize server,I tried something like *Win1.server* or similars but I failed.
How could i pass it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: With WPF you should try to use MVVM - so all the Data Passing challenges are handled easily. It will take some time initially but is worth the pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is to make server public like this:

```
public MyServer_Database Server { get; set; }
```

Then you can call it in `MainWindow` with:

```
Win1.Server.GetDataFromUserList();
```

But this is not a good approach. Better approach is to abstract away these kind of operations in different classes via MVVM. Read more about MVVM and you'll find great approaches.

**Edit**

You should also do one one of these two things:

1. Don't close `Win1` instead do `this.Hide();`
2. Keep the instance of `MyServer_Database` in `MainWindow` by passing it to the constructor of `Win1`.

You should put this in `MainWindow`

```
public MyServer_Database Server { get; set; }
```

and When needed call this:

```
var Win1 = new LoginWindow(Server);
```

Then you have access to `Server` object in `MainWindow`

Comment: But my app only logins to the server when i press the button,
if I change MyServer_Database Server to public MyServer_Database Server { get; set; } will my mainwindow call it properly? Because my login window runs this login method not my MainWindow

Comment: The problem might be unclear for me. Can you show the login window? Does it operate correctly with server and get the login result?

Comment: I got a System.nullreference.exception when i called a server method on my mainwindow after succesfully login from login window

Comment: You should not close it. Keep the instance first. See the edit.